# USB0 changed the mode due to EMI using AM1808

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, arm, embedded-linux, usb-drive

I am using AM1808 for my application and using Ubuntu 12.04 for development purpose.

I have cross compiled my kernel for USB0 on Host mode.

Due to the issue of EMI my USB0 mode has been changed from Host to Peripheral.

I need to make USB0 remain in the HOST even after EMI generation.

Is there any way to handle this from software side ?

Comment: Fix the hardware.  Are you doing a region RF certification or do you mean something else by *EMI*?  Is the signal degraded and non-functional in host more?

Comment: Yes I know i need to change the hardware but immediately i need to change by software side.Yes EMI means Electro Magnetic Interference. Due to EMI i found two different behaviour 1. Automatic Reboot and 2. USB0 mode changed from Host to peripheral.EMI generates around 2V of spike on the HID pin, due to which processor's function is unexpected.

Comment: You could restart the controller.  However, if the USB impedance is not correct, then it may never work.  [EMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference) is usually near field RF noise.  Cross talk, ground bounce, impedance mis-match, etc are slightly different.  Try shorter USB cables and different PCs/Hubs if possible.